# Logcat error description : Button launch crashes app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-emulator

There was some permission constraint in manifest file .... I removed it but the application still crashes on button click....Rest of the buttons are working great..... It started happening when i used the Notepad sample code in the SDK to impement a similar "save Notes" for my application

These are the new logcat details

---

```
   09-13 03:23:42.743: E/AudioTrack(776): Could not get audio output for stream type 3
09-13 03:23:42.743: E/SoundPool(776): Error creating AudioTrack
09-13 03:23:43.363: D/dalvikvm(776): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 104K, 3% free 10299K/10524K, paused 61ms, total 95ms
09-13 03:23:43.394: I/dalvikvm-heap(776): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.121MB for 3094560-byte allocation
09-13 03:23:43.563: D/dalvikvm(776): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3542K, 28% free 9779K/13548K, paused 172ms, total 173ms
09-13 03:23:44.223: I/Choreographer(776): Skipped 329 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 03:23:44.493: I/Choreographer(776): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 03:23:44.913: I/Choreographer(776): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 03:23:45.693: I/Choreographer(776): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
09-13 03:23:51.364: E/AudioTrack(776): Could not get audio output for stream type 3
09-13 03:23:51.364: E/SoundPool(776): Error creating AudioTrack
09-13 03:23:51.914: D/AndroidRuntime(776): Shutting down VM
09-13 03:23:51.914: W/dalvikvm(776): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hellog.diwesh.NugaBest/helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NotesList}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.example.android.notepad.NotePadProvider from ProcessRecord{41986ad8 776:hellog.diwesh.NugaBest/u0a10049} (pid=776, uid=10049) that is not exported from uid 10050
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.example.android.notepad.NotePadProvider from ProcessRecord{41986ad8 776:hellog.diwesh.NugaBest/u0a10049} (pid=776, uid=10049) that is not exported from uid 10050
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1431)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1385)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2611)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:4515)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2036)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1149)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:398)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:357)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.Activity.managedQuery(Activity.java:1765)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NotesList.onCreate(NotesList.java:104)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
09-13 03:23:52.024: E/AndroidRuntime(776):  ... 11 more
09-13 03:23:56.654: I/Process(776): Sending signal. PID: 776 SIG: 9
```

---

Androidmanifst

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hellog.diwesh.NugaBest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.MyApplication" 
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/nuga"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_HealthCareActivity_Intro"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>








        // 4. Layout Management

        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.FileSiganlDisplay"
            android:label="FileSiganlDisplay" />
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_WebJoinActivity"
            android:label="NUGA_WebJoinActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NUGA_MainMenuActivity"
            android:label="NUGA_MainMenuActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.BTSmartSlavemodule"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="SmartSlavemodule" />
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.BTDeviceListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/select_device"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />

        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.SnapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_snap" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.ImagesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_images" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.HelpActivity"
            android:label="@string/Help" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.AboutDevice"
            android:label="@string/aboutus" >
        </activity>




        // Notepad Application




         <activity android:name="NotesList" android:label="@string/title_notes_list">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />

                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="NoteEditor"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        >
            <!-- This filter says that we can view or edit the data of
                 a single note -->
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_edit">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
                <action android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.action.EDIT_NOTE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- This filter says that we can create a new note inside
                 of a directory of notes.  The INSERT action creates an
                 empty note; the PASTE action initializes a new note from
                 the current contents of the clipboard. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PASTE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name="TitleEditor"
            android:label="@string/title_edit_title"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_edit"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
            <!-- This activity implements an alternative action that can be
                 performed on notes: editing their title.  It can be used as
                 a default operation if the user invokes this action, and is
                 available as an alternative action for any note data. -->
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_title">
                <!-- This is the action we perform.  It is a custom action we
                     define for our application, not a generic VIEW or EDIT
                     action since we are not a general note viewer/editor. -->
                <action android:name="helog.diwesh.NugaBest.action.EDIT_TITLE" />
                <!-- DEFAULT: execute if being directly invoked. -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <!-- ALTERNATIVE: show as an alternative action when the user is
                     working with this type of data. -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
                <!-- SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE: show as an alternative action the user
                     can perform when selecting this type of data. -->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.SELECTED_ALTERNATIVE" />
                <!-- This is the data type we operate on. -->
                <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="NotesLiveFolder" android:label="@string/live_folder_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/live_folder_notes">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_LIVE_FOLDER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>







    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

Comment: post the relevant code pls

Comment: what you deleted in manifest file.

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime(786): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {hellog.diwesh.NugaBest/helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NotesList}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: @Raghunandan: Buddy i already posted all the code in the previous question .. Had to separate the two because he website was not allowing me to include any more characters

Comment: @AnshSharma atleas post the manifest file. it says you have not declared activity in manifest file

Comment: Have you declared Your activity in Manifest

Comment: @Yugesh: <provider android:name="NotePadProvider"
            android:authorities="com.google.provider.NotePad"
            android:exported="false">
            <grant-uri-permission android:pathPattern=".*" />
        </provider>

Comment: You have forgot to add any one activity into your Manifest file. So please recheck it once.

Comment: @all : Yes the activity is declared

Comment: better to post your manifest file here and this line of code NUGA_MainMenuActivity.java:150

Comment: @AnshSharma your package name is **hellog.diwesh.NugaBest** but you declared in all activity like  **helog.diwesh.NugaBest** you missed **l** .

Comment: @AnshSharma check your package names in your classes and manifest file. should match

Comment: @Yugesh: Strangely everything works if that is the error .... I think the package name is automatically resolved . Also i noted under my SRC on the left there is a package : hellog.diwesh.NugaBest which is gray and cant be expanded and  underneath that is the package : helog.diwesh.NugaBest and al my files are under that

Comment: @AnshSharma now it works or not.

Comment: @yugesh : No ... still throwing the error on button click .. ihaave pasted the new logcat in the same  question and  removed the old log

Comment: @all : Hii i have now explicitly mentioned my package name in the manifest with each activity associated ... And now the log error says permission denial .... Please help ... I have updated the logcat now

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared NoteList activity in your manifest file.

Please include this in your manifest.

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {hellog.diwesh.NugaBest/helog.diwesh.NugaBest.NotesList}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

It means that you forgot to declare your `NotesList activity` inside manifest file and if you declared then there would be problem with your `packagename` in declaration, please cross check `activity & package name` in your manifest file and confirm that you declared correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Error here,  You have not declared in proper way

```
<activity android:name="NotesList" android:label="@string/title_notes_list">
```

make it like this

```
<activity android:name=".NotesList" android:label="@string/title_notes_list">
```

Error in your package name your package name is `hellog.diwesh.NugaBest` but you declared in all activity like `helog.diwesh.NugaBest` change according to that.

Comment: don't think that is the problem

Comment: check it once that is the problem here. activity should have package.

Comment: do check this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html. example has  `package="com.example.android.notepad">` and activity entry as `activity android:name="NotesList" android:label="@string/title_notes_list">`

Comment: @all i did the changes and this is how the new Log looks like